# ERROR ITMS-90596: "Invalid Bundle. The asset catalog at 'Payload/Limon chilli.app/Assets.car' can't be read

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode8, ios10

While uploading ipa file to application loader I'am getting this type of error.
I'am using  sierra 10.12.1 and x-code Version 8.1 (8B62). How to solve this?

```
ERROR ITMS-90596: "Invalid Bundle. The asset catalog at 'Payload/Limon
chilli.app/Assets.car' can't be read. Try rebuilding the app with a non-beta 
version of Xcode and submit it again."
```

Comment: An error shows that you are trying to submit the app from Xcode beta version.

Comment: then i should be download x-code 8.2 right?

Comment: you need an alpha version of Xcode.

Comment: updated mac os and x-code getting same error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is really weird issue people are facing from new version of `XCode` and `macOS Sierra`. There are multiple ways you can solve this error are as follows:

1. Use latest XCode 8.2.1 and macOS Sierra 10.12.1, and upload archive from new XCode. Get [latest XCode](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12) from here
2. Archive your app, Create .ipa file with options `Save for iOS App Store Deplyment` and upload it using `Application Loader`.

One of these options should work as I faced same issue and fixed it by doing both of this for 2 times till now. Prefer #1 as you don't have to use any other tool for uploading build.

Comment: i have updated macOS Sierra 10.12.1, and X-code Version 8.2.1 (8C1002) again iam gettng same error//

Comment: You may need to uninstall the beta xcode (delete it from wherever you keep it)

Answer (score 5):

In my case I used old Application Loader and saw this error. To launch latest Application Loader chose `Xcode -> Open Developer Tool -> Application Loader`

Comment: That was the reason in my case too

Comment: I just uploaded directly from the XCode Organizer instead of exporting to ipa and uploading with Application Loader and it worked.  I'm guessing the version of the application loader I'm using is somehow wrong or mismatched with my XCode version.

Answer (score 0):

I had selected the Application Loader by searching (<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>). There were a number of Application Loaders in the search result (since I had older versions of Xcode in my system). Selected the one on the top of the list and uploaded the ipa file. Thats when i got this error.

The issue was fixed when I selected the Application Loader from my latest Xcode, (`Xcode -> Open Developer Tools -> Application Loader`).

Answer (score 0):

This issue is getting when a user trying to upload an ipa using Transporter/Application laoder which is created with old version of xcode,
 - Create ipa with latest Xcode version and Transporter